# How to delete the .apk after installation

Tags: android, android-sdcard, apk

I am using the following program to download and install an apk. How can I remove the apk from the sdcard after successful installation? What I tried is:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/filename.apk");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

But it will delete the file before installation.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
  try {
    URL url = new URL( weburl +"username="+usename+"&password="+usepass +"&apk="+apk);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.apk");

    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0;

    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
     fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }
    fileOutput.close();
    // this.checkUnknownSourceEnability();
    // this.initiateInstallation();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/filename.apk"));
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);

  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}

private void installApk(){
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/filename.apk"));
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out when an installation is completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176645/how-to-find-out-when-an-installation-is-completed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete an application (\*.apk) after installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984546/delete-an-application-apk-after-installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a broadcast receiver that will notify you when installation will complete and at that time you can fire your code for delete apk.

please see this question

[How to find out when an installation is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176645/how-to-find-out-when-an-installation-is-completed)